# Quantified variables without case-based analysis in traits

Tags: syntax, functional-programming, traits

In almost every functional language I know of, quantified type variables are identified using case:

```haskell
-- haskell / almost everything miranda-influenced
repl :: a -> Int -> List a
-- quantified vars are lowercase, concrete types/kinds are uppercase
```

However, you can do it without case analysis, using explicit quantification:

```haskell
-- this also happens to be valid haskell assuming -XRankNTypes
repl :: forall a, a -> Int -> List a
```

You then, however, encounter a bit of an issue when making trait/typeclass instance declarations:

```haskell
instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) where
    ...

vs

-- This is not, as far as I know, valid haskell
instance forall a, Show a => Show (Maybe a) where
    ...
```

To be perfectly blunt, that syntax isn't amazing. The actual content, ie `Show (Maybe a)` gets lost in the requirements and quantification.
However, without using case as a syntactic element, i'm not seeing a better way to do it.
Some things i've considered, but am still open to:

```haskell
using `a, ...` === the conventional `forall a, ...` - more unclear
using symbols (ie the actual forall symbol) - more confusing
```

I am fully open to a different instance syntax if it helps mitigate this issue.

more info:
My language is close enough to this haskell syntax that any modification to said haskell syntax would transfer over reasonably, so feel free to response in haskell/psudohaskell.

Comment: I think F#'s syntax for this is `'a`, i.e. an identifier preceded by a single quote. If I'm understanding the purpose of this syntax in Haskell (a language I don't use).

Comment: @kaya3 I think that's what MLs do as well? I think the question is about not syntactically differentiating type variables in general (rather than *just* by casing), but that's definitely good to mention.

Comment: @UnrelatedString Yes, I would prefer to not disambiguate by any sort of lexical convention, but the `'a` syntax isn't the worst if I don't find a better solution. Thank you both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest "stealing" syntax from [Lean 4](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/type_classes.html), it's pretty clean and concise, and doesn't depend on the case of variables or much punctuation:

```haskell
class Foo (X : Type) where
  myshow : X -> String

instance [Foo X] [Foo y] : Foo (X × y) where
  myshow x :=
    let ⟨a, B⟩ := x
    "(" ++ Foo.myshow a ++ ", " ++ Foo.myshow B ++ ")"
```

I mix cases of both type-level and value-level variables for illustrative purposes.